# Scroll Horizontal on UITableViewCollection

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview

I'm using a UICollectionView to display images.
So I create the Collection programmatically, and I init the layout to set like this :

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
howTo = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
self.howTo?.collectionViewLayout = layout
howTo!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "howToCell")
```

But the scrolling is still vertical, I have no idea why... I set horizontal before and after creating collection just to be sure.
If anyone could help

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your content size? Scroll views in iOS scroll only in directions in which there is content to scroll to. Try making the collection view bigger than the view horizontally, using

`let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width * 2, self.view.bounds.height)
 howTo = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)`

and you should find that your view scrolls horizontally.

[Make sure to take a look at Apple's scroll view docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html)

Comment: I just try your solution and that didn't work too.
I'll copy/paste you the code, maybe you could tell.
       howTo = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
    self.howTo?.collectionViewLayout = layout
    self.view.addSubview(howTo!)
    howTo!.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
      make.top.equalTo(readMoreText.snp_bottom).offset(15)
      make.leading.equalTo(self.view).offset(5)
      make.trailing.equalTo(self.view).offset(-5)
      make.height.equalTo(115)
    }